# Android Encrypting and Decrypting a resource file in a App

Tags: android, encryption, resources

In Android how to decrypt a text file present in resource folder and use the data in it. So that i can maintain a encrypted file inside the resource folder in that apk. Help me to get this.

Comment: This info is not sufficient. Please tell us how will you encypt the file? Public key cryptography or Private key? Which algorithm 3DES,AES,RSA etc?

Comment: @Shashank Kadne: I need to make my text file present in resource folder as encrypted one, when the app is launched it get decrypted and used in app. Basic way is using single key we need to encrypt and decrypt the files but the key will present inside the class files so it can also be cracked but if i want to make the key as device specific how to achieve that and which method will be good? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the javax.crypto.Cipher packages.

Example here:

[Android File Cryptography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156545/android-file-cryptography)